# nodejs on windows Cluster High memory useage

Tags: node.js, windows, http, memory

I use express static plugins,Windows 2008 64bit,8G ram,10Gb net,node-6.9.x 64bit

```
var cluster = require("cluster");
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
if(cluster.isMaster()){
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    cluster.fork();
}else{
  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();
  var http = require("http");
  app.use(express.static(""));
  http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
}
```

Memory grow very fast,from 1Gb to 8Gb about five minutes.at this time about 1500 connections.outgoing bandwidth 300Mb/10Gb,every worker process about 150MB,Master Process 30MB。

```
System performance monitor show 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
receive|           using 7.8G                     | free 100Mb
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Memory is used by who? About 15 minutes,worker process crash.

I try http-server module(npm install http-server ),The same result。

Comment: how do you do the 1500 connections test?

Comment: System perofrmance monitor --> TCPv4-->Connection Active

Comment: I don't understand why this sample code would create 1500 connections by default.

Comment: That is server,have 1500 Client.

Comment: Is it your production server? I wonder if it's serving large static files and it may cause problems.

Comment: It as HLS server.Every segment about 500KB~1MB.I use nginx . very stable.

Comment: why do you want to use express server to serve static files? I am just wondering because I think nginx is better to serve static files than node.js server.

Answer (score 0):

I use ab test for 10 seconds testing your code( with a little bit changes) on my laptop, it works well.
Changes are `cluster.isMaster` and `app.use(express.static("/"));`

```
var cluster = require("cluster");
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
if(cluster.isMaster){
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    cluster.fork();
}else{
  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();
  var http = require("http");
  app.use(express.static("/"));
  http.createServer(app).listen(8080);
}
```

Results are:

```
Benchmarking 127.0.0.1 (be patient)
Completed 5000 requests
Completed 10000 requests
Completed 15000 requests
Completed 20000 requests
Completed 25000 requests
Finished 26960 requests


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        127.0.0.1
Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /
Document Length:        13 bytes

Concurrency Level:      300
Time taken for tests:   10.023 seconds
Complete requests:      26960
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Non-2xx responses:      27097
Total transferred:      5717467 bytes
HTML transferred:       352261 bytes
Requests per second:    2689.93 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       111.527 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.372 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          557.09 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   3.1      0     498
Processing:    94  109  46.2    104     609
Waiting:       12   79  48.5     77     567
Total:         94  109  46.3    104     609
```

Comment: Yes,I also  test The LAN. No problem，My server run on the Internet,I think slow connection affects.static file about 1MB~.

Comment: static plugins use send module, send module final use pipe,Because slow connection, By system Cache?

Comment: Where is code above from? Could you pls show all the code?